# что происходит с возвращаемой функции в void функции

Tags: c++, c, функции, return, void

у меня только один вопрос : что происходит с возвращаемым методом в методе который не может ничего возвращать .
Что конкретно происходит в методе `handlesum` , куда возвращается значения метода `sum`

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int sum(int a,int b){
    return a+b;
}

void handlesum(int a,int b){
    sum(a,b); // ЧТО КОНКРЕТНО ЗДЕСЬ ПРОИСХОДИТ 
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    handlesum(1,2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ничего. Если компилятор без оптимизатора - ну, какой-то код суммирования создаст, результат - в помойку, ну, а если компилятор поумнее - то и этого не будет.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function

Comment: *ЧТО КОНКРЕТНО ЗДЕСЬ ПРОИСХОДИТ* -- вызов функции

Comment: @dlm0n , я прекрасно понимаю что там вызывается функция , вопрос был в том куда возвращается значения

Comment: В регистры процессора или на стек или никуда. Очень много вариантов в зависимости от архитектуры (ABI), компилятора, его параметров, ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ничего. Если компилятор без оптимизатора - ну, какой-то код суммирования создаст, результат - в помойку, ну, а если компилятор поумнее - то и этого не будет.

Вот, [убедитесь](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/M43qvq):

```
sum(int, int):
        lea     eax, [rdi+rsi]
        ret
handlesum(int, int):
        ret
main:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
_GLOBAL__sub_I_sum(int, int):
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
        call    std::ios_base::Init::Init() [complete object constructor]
        mov     edx, OFFSET FLAT:__dso_handle
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
        add     rsp, 8
        jmp     __cxa_atexit
```

В общем случае: возвращаемое значение просто не используется, вот и все.

Answer (score 5):

Там ничего не происходит. И ничего это не даст. Функции, которые возвращают void, то есть не возвращают просто выполняют свой функционал, описанный в виде операторов: присваивают значения переменным, выводят текст, считывают ввод и т.д.

Во-вторых, если вы просто так вызовите функцию, которая что-то возвращает, то она выполнится, даже куда-нибудь что-нибудь выведет, если в ней есть фукнция cout, НО свое значение, которая она вернула никуда она не запишет. Поэтмому функции, которые возвращают значение обычно пишут так:

```
int a = sum(x, y);
```

ИЛи другой тип данных.

При вызове фукнции, которая возвращает значение, значение, которое она возращает ПОДСТАВЛЯЕТСЯ ВМЕСТО ВЫЗОВА ФУНКЦИИ.
Например:

```
if (isMoreThatZero(3) == true)) cout << "HELLO";
```

Выведет HELLO, так как 3 больше, чем 0 (эта фукнция проверяет, больше ли число, чем 0), значит значение true подставится вместо вызова функции и мы получим это:

```
if (true == true)
```

В вашем случае это значение, которое подставится вместо sum(a, b) ничего не будет значить, так как с ним вы ничего не делаете: не используете в цикле, не проверяете в условии, не присваиваете в переменную и т.д.

А вот методы void для того и нужны, чтобы вызывать их просто так: они выполнят ссвой функционал и движение по коду продолжится дальше.

Answer (score 2):

Без никаких оптимизаций при возвращении из функции `sum` вызывается деструктор временного возвращаемого объекта. Так как деструктор в простом типе `int` - элементарный (его просто нет), то вызываться деструктор не будет. А само возвращаемое значение останется лежать мусором в памяти стека.

С оптимизацией возвращаемое значение может остаться только в регистрах процессора. Память в стеке выделяться не будет.

При возвращении сложных типов (классов) будет всегда создаваться временный объект и после завершении строчки кода этот временный объект будет ликвидирован.

Пример :

```
class Hard{
  ...};

Hard func(void){
  ...
  return {..}}

void meth ( Hard h ) {
  ...}

int main(){
  meth ( func ( ) ) ;
  }
```

Сначала вызывается метод `func`, при возврате значения он создаёт временный объект `Hard`, расположенный  в стеке. Этот временный объект будет в рабочем состоянии до тех пор пока другая функция `meth` не закончит с ней работу. Затем будет вызван его деструктор.

```
вызывается func
..
при возврате создаётся Hard
отдаётся функции meth
..
meth завершился
все временные объекты ликвидируются
и вызывается деструктор ~Hard();
```